# npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/gulp-sass/-/gulp-sass-2.3.2.tgz npm

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I have downloaded the project instead of using "ionic start --v2 myApp tabs" as the command gave me following error:
[image: error downloading project]

Also npm install gives me error:
[image: npm install error]

npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/gulp-sass/-/gulp-sass-2.3.2.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 403.

Comment: Can you post the node version and also looks like your company has a firewall, and it is blocking downloads

Comment: v6.10.2 yeah maybe.